# Android error ! when i create override onstart method ..as given below help me

Tags: java, android, firebase

when i try to execute firebase  mAuth/
 it gives ;(semicolon expected) and annotataions not allowed here
[image]

Comment: You've posted an image of your code, consider adding it as a text as it makes it easier for us to help you. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you cant define method inside a method

```
onCreate(){
 //your code
}


onStart(){
// code
}
```